# Правильный заголовочный файл для std::cout

Tags: c++

Почему при включении только заголовка `ostream` *Visual Studio 2015* не может найти `cout`, а при влючении `iostream` - всё нормально? Код такой:

```
#include <ostream> // если заменить на iostream, то всё компилируется

int main()
{
std::cout;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Для каждого имени из пространства имен `std` существует один или несколько, связанных с ним *include*-файлов. Какой конкретно файл нужно подключать директивой `#include`, чтобы программа гарантированно была переносимой между различными компиляторами, описано в Стандарте C++. Для имени `std::cout` таким файлом является `<iostream>` (см. п.27.4 Стандарта).

Answer (score 4):

Да, переменная `std::cout` объявлена в `<iostream>`.